# Will I miss out on anything major by skipping over the various Monokuma Theatres?

Tags: danganronpa-2-goodbye-despair

I'm enjoying the game and am excited to be playing through it, however I have found the various monokuma/monami theatres and monologues to not add much value and be unenjoyable so I've taken to skipping over them for the most part.

Are these actually important at all?